# Pop up Alert based on prompt result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an alert based on the answer on the prompt, prompt is working but it does not show the pop up alert message after answering the prompt. Here is my script hoping someone can help please

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.prompt('Please provide your shift on the box below.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  if (result == "morning") {
    alert("We have " + Sheet17.D3 + " OT hours for TLs and " + Sheet17.D11 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "dawn") {
    alert("We have " + Sheet17.D2 + " OT hours for TLs and " + Sheet17.D10 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "EM") {
    alert("We have " + Sheet17.D4 + " OT hours for TLs and " + Sheet17.D12 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "Mid") {
    alert("We have " + Sheet17.D5 + " OT hours for TLs and " + Sheet17.D13 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "evening") {
    alert("We have " + Sheet17.D6 + " OT hours for TLs and " + Sheet17.D14 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "night") {
    alert("We have " + Sheet17.D7 + " OT hours for TLs and " + Sheet17.D15 + " for QAs!");
  }
}
```

Tried different scripts but still not working

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add the textual error message. P.S.  The Google Apps Script runtime engines, contrary as web browser runtimes engines, don't include support to `Window` global object.

Comment: There is no error message it just does not show the pop up message that I was expecting based on the response on the prompt say if the user entered "morning" it will show We have (data from Sheet17!D3) OT hours for TLs and (data from Sheet17!D11) for QAs.

Comment: Look at the execution logs.

Comment: it says Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.

Answer (score 0):

The script has several problems

1. It's using a reserved function name that will cause that the script run every time that the spreadsheet is opened. It might work for the spreadsheet owner but it will not work for spreadsheet editors because restrictions introduced by Google several years ago that prevent that a simple on open trigger opens a user interface element.
2. The variable `result` has not being declared.
3. The variable `Sheet17` has not being declared.
4. The variable `alert` has not being declared.

The following function shows how to use `Ui.prompt`

```
function myFunction(){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Please provide your shift on the box below.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  if(response.getResponseText() === 'morning'){
     ui.alert('Morning message')
  }
}
```

Note: The code should be added on a script bounded to a spreadsheet.

To learn about how to get values from a spreadsheet please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response

Comment: Im really new to this and still trying to figure everything out could you help me please

Comment: this does not show the prompt though and I got the error Error 
Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.
myFunction @ Untitled.gs:2

Comment: That error occurs in when using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` in a stand alone project. The code should be used in a bounded script. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: I tried this but the other result of responses wont work only the result for morning

Comment: function onOpen(){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Please provide your shift on the box below.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  if(response.getResponseText() === 'morning'){
     ui.alert('We have 191 hours available for TLs and 327 hours available for QAs');
     if(response.getResponseText() === 'dawn'){
     ui.alert('We have 43 hours available for TLs and 71 hours available for QAs');

Comment: Why do you insist on using `onOpen` as the function name?

Comment: Anyway... the code in your last comment has missing `{`. If you need further help, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onMyOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const result = ui.prompt('Please provide your shift on the box below.', ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh17 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet17");
  const [D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7] = sh17.getRange("D2:D7").getValues().flat();
  const [D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15] = sh17.getRange("D10:D15").getValues().flat(); 
  if (result == "morning") {
    alert("We have " + D3 + " OT hours for TLs and " + D11 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "dawn") {
    alert("We have " + D2 + " OT hours for TLs and " + D10 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "EM") {
    alert("We have " + D4 + " OT hours for TLs and " + D12 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "Mid") {
    alert("We have " + D5 + " OT hours for TLs and " + D13 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "evening") {
    alert("We have " + D6 + " OT hours for TLs and " + D14 + " for QAs!");
  }
  if (result == "night") {
    alert("We have " + D7 + " OT hours for TLs and " + D15 + " for QAs!");
  }
}
```

Run the following function to create installable trigger

```
function createOnMyOpenTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyOpen").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyOpen").forSpreadsheet(ss).onOpen().create();
  }
}
```